# How to move file to specific directory folder based on select input?

Tags: php, html-select

Below is what i have so far, I'm renaming the file on upload by microtime then moving it to a folder entitled "pdf-cv", however, what I need to do is move it do a folder base on the select input (additionally, would be great if I could create that folder in the directory if it doesn't already exist.) Any help is much appreciated.

**Example**: If a user selects "Option1" then uploads a file, then that file will be moved to a folder in the directory entitled "Option1".

The select input:

```
<select id="categories" name="categories" class="categories">
<option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="">option 1</option>
<option value="">option 2 </option>
<option value="">option 3 </option>
</select>
```

The upload form:

```
<form action ="pdf_upload.php" id="cv_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="fileUpload text-center cv_select">
    <span>Select File</span>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="upload" id="pdf_input" />
</div>   
<canvas class="center-block pdf_canvas" id="the-canvas" style=""><p class="preview_text">Preview</p></canvas>    
<input class="cv_upload" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

pdf_upload.php content:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = "pdf-cv/";
$allowed_ext = "pdf";
$max_size = "5000000";

$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file'] ['name']);
$extension = $extension[extension];
$allowed_paths = explode(", ", $allowed_ext);
for($i = 0; $i < count($allowed_paths); $i++) {
if ($allowed_paths [$i] == "$extension") {
    $ok = "1";
}
}


if ($ok == "1")  {
    if($_FILES['file']['size'] > $max_size)
    {
        print "File is too big!";
        exit;
    }


if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$uploaddir.''. $newfilename);
 header("Location: new_begining_index.php#home"); 
}

print "Your CV has been successfully uploaded!";    

} else {
print "Incorrect file extension!";
}

?>
```

Comment: you could use a case/switch for this http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php and based on a POST array. That would be the simplest method, IMO.

Comment: I understand in theory of using superglobals but in practice I'm not so sure how to put it all together. could you show me a simple example and i'll go from there?

Comment: see an answer given below. I also had that method in mind. quite a few ways to do this actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first want to give your select input actual values:

```
<select id="categories" name="categories" class="categories">
<option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="Option1">option 1</option>
<option value="Option2">option 2 </option>
<option value="Option3">option 3 </option>
</select>
```

Then validate the input, check if the directory exists or create it. I'm using `die()` in the example below for error checking, which isn't the most graceful way of doing it but should answer your question regardless:

```
$uploaddir = "pdf-cv/";

// make sure a category was selected
if (!isset($_POST['categories']) || trim($_POST['categories']) == '') {
    die("no category selected");
}

// validate input against a whitelist
if (!in_array($_POST['categories'], array('Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'))) {
    die("don't hack me bruh");
}

// make directory if it doesn't exist
$newdir = $uploaddir . $_POST['categories'];
if (!file_exists($newdir)) {
    mkdir($newdir, 0755, true);
}
```

Now you can move the file as normal:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $newdir . '/' . $newfilename);
```

Note that for the `$uploaddir` you may need to use an absolute path rather than a relative one. For example: `/var/www/public_html/my_project/pdf-cv/`. If you don't know what your absolute path is, this can usually be found in the `$_SERVER` superglobal:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SERVER);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks, so this should create a folder within pdf-cv of the select input?

Comment: keeps coming up with the error message. "don't hack me bruh" http://pastebin.com/7ry9KBiW

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham See updated answer. Make sure you have actual values in your `select` options. The example you posted has `value=""`, you need to have `value="Option1"` etc...

Comment: Yeah, I added the values, think there is something i'm doing wrong. http://pastebin.com/YNRBuLFM

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham Sorry, the code is difficult to read because of the formatting. It looks like you've got some logic out of order. I've tried to fix it here: http://pastebin.com/P9y1GxzJ

Comment: It now states "no category selected"

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham double check your form names and variable names and make sure there are no mis-matches or spelling mistakes.

Comment: Found the mistake, rather embarrassed I forgot to include the select input in the form tag. lol